# Using require.js, how can I include a file defining a number of modules but only keep the ones I need?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I have a reusable set of Javascript components that I would like to bundle into a single file, and another web application using it. This library defines a number of modules (in the RequireJS sense), one some of which the web application is actually using.

Is it possible to accomplish the following:

- Optimize the source files for the library with r.js, producing a single output file containing all the exported modules.
- Depend on this one file in another application, also using RequireJS, and optimize again - keeping only the code for the modules actually required in the web application.

Effectively, I'm looking to get the same results as dumping all the source files of the library into the application and optimizing once, but with the added benefit of being able to ship the library as a single file. Is this possible to achieve using RequireJS?